# Correct upload limit in PHP to work with Cloudflare’s upload limit

Tags: php, upload, cloudflare

In the PHP config are 3 variables which are important for the upload:

`memory_limit`

`post_max_size`

`upload_max_filesize`

where `memory_limit` has to be larger than `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`
and
where `post_max_size` has to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`

`memory_limit` is usually set to `256M` in my environments, so that’s way over the limit and nothing to worry about.

However, the problem lies with `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`. The question is, which of these two variables have to be `100M`, to comply with Cloudflare’s upload limit?

Is it

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 99M
```

or

```
post_max_size = 101M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/correct-upload-limit-in-php-to-work-with-cloudflares-upload-limit/202359/4?u=d3strukt0r

Applies to `post_max_size` and therefore also `upload_max_filesize`. Safest is to put both `100M`